# laço de repetição com duas estruturas condicionais - python

Tags: python, loop, if, lógica, while

Tenho uma estrutura condicional que executo dentro de um laço de repetição, isso para negociações tipo long, gostaria de incorporar o inverso se ao invés de long fosse short.

```
#LONG
if (direcao != direcao_anterior and direcao == 1 and positions_total == 0):
#if(fechamento > media_8 and positions_total == 0):
    print("buy")       
#close position long
elif(fechamento < media_8 and positions_total > 0):
    print("close position")        
elif(fechamento > media_8 and positions_total > 0):
    print("we have an open position")       
else:
    print("searching")



#SHORT
if (direcao != direcao_anterior and direcao == -1 and positions_total == 0):
#if(fechamento > media_8 and positions_total == 0):
    print("short")        
#close position short
elif(fechamento > media_8 and positions_total > 0):
    print("close position")        
elif(fechamento < media_8 and positions_total > 0):
    print("we have an open position")        
else:
    print("searching")
```

Comment: Não ficou claro o que deseja fazer e seria interessante construir um [mcve].

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim, acho que facilita.

```py
def negociacao_long():
    if (direcao != direcao_anterior and direcao == 1 and positions_total == 0):
        print("buy")
    elif(fechamento < media_8 and positions_total > 0):
        print("close position")
    elif(fechamento > media_8 and positions_total > 0):
        print("we have an open position")
    else:
        print("searching")

def negociacao_short():
    if (direcao != direcao_anterior and direcao == -1 and positions_total == 0):
        print("short")
    elif(fechamento > media_8 and positions_total > 0):
        print("close position")
    elif(fechamento < media_8 and positions_total > 0):
        print("we have an open position")
    else:
        print("searching")

negociacoes = {
    "long": negociacao_long,
    "short": negociacao_short
}

tipo_negociacao = "long"
negociacoes.get(tipo_negociacao, negociacao_long)()
```